# How do I define a private final field that is initialized using an optional constructor argument with a default value?

Tags: dart

Suppose I have this situation:

```dart
class Foo {
  final _bar;
  Foo([bar = 'hello']);
}
```

In Dart, how do I initialize `_bar`, given that it's private?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the initializer list.

```dart
class Foo {
  final _bar;
  Foo([bar = 'hello']) : _bar = bar;
}
```

The initializer list is run before the constructor body.

Comment: Is there a way to make the default value, an instance of an object?
i.e. [bar = new Bar()]?

Comment: Please ask that as a new Stack Overflow question. Thanks!